# Hosting Ruby Scripts online

Tags: ruby, hosting

Can anyone recommend a free service for hosting Ruby scripts? It's not Rails, it's not even anything too complicated, just a bunch of simple ruby scripts?

Comment: Depends on what these scripts do.

Answer (score 3):

[Heroku.com](http://heroku.com) is by far the easiest way to get a simple script online.

Comment: You can put what you like on there. I use Sinatra, simple rack applications, and it gives you 'heroku console', background jobs, databases, and so on - so there's no requirement for a UI / web front end.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is share your ruby scripts (the scripts don't run on the server but are available for others to download and use), use [Rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/) and/or [Rubygems](http://rubygems.org/).